# How to rename multiple files in efficient way?

Tags: python, file, optimization

I have created a program to rename multiple files in a directory. My goal was to serialize them and pad with 0 depending on amount of files in directory (example: for 11 jpg files last one would be 011.jpg). I want make it work efficient with large amounts of files on multiple platforms. Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path

number = 1
amount = 0
files = []

directory = Path.home() / 'Photos'

for file in directory.iterdir():
    if file.is_file():
        files.append(file)
        amount+=1

for file in files:
    file.replace(f'{directory}/{number:0{len(str(amount))+1}}{file.suffix}')
    number += 1
```

1) Is there way to avoid two loops? First for getting amount of elements - for padding purpose. Then second for renaming. If not is there something that I can improve to make it work better?

2) Is it universal way to get to users photos directory? Not depending on platform or system language?

Comment: To get the count of files in the directory it looks like you have to use the iterator, which means that you won't get a full count of files for your naming scheme until you complete your first iteration. Your renaming operation looks pretty efficient as it stands. Are you also looking to traverse subdirectories? How many files are you concerned about encountering?

Comment: I don't want to run through subdirectories. Only base one. It can contain thousands of files. I was also thinking about seting second loop as first '
for file in directory.iterdir():' to avoid creating and storing list with elements, but then I have to check if condition once again - so that won't make it more efficient I think. Do you know how to reach users photos directory while they are using platform with different language? It can be named for example: Photos / Bilder / Obrazy, etc.

Comment: Thousands of files should take barely a moment on a modern machine, so i don't think you need to worry about efficiency. The file object handles should be lightweight as well. It looks like you can query this programmatically depending on the OS. For windows try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/7550097). For OSX I was not able to find anything about Photos being a standard location, except for some shreds of using Applescript (which can be a bit tedious from python)